# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle2x-1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ are isomorphic rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was thinking in use the fundamental morphism theorem. But in that case I would need the kernel were $\langle2x-1\rangle$ is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$Consider the ring homomorphism
\begin{align}
\phi :\ &\Z[x] \to \Q\\
&f \mapsto f(1/2)
\end{align}
$f \in \ker(\phi)$ iff $f(1/2) = 0$ iff $(x - \frac{1}{2}) \mid f$ in $\Q[x]$, so that 
$$
f = \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) g = (2 x - 1) h
$$
for some $g, h \in \Q[x]$. But then, calculating [contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content#Over_the_rationals), $\Z \ni c(f) = c(2 x - 1) c(h) = c(h)$, so that $h \in \Z[x]$ and $f \in \langle2x-1\rangle$.